# How to navigate to Jetpack Compose function in dynamic feature module from app or another dfm?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

With Fragments and Activities it's possible to open Fragment or Activity in dynamic feature module.

For instance app module can navigate to login or stage dynamic feature modules using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.hopinstream.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_login"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_stageFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_stage"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>

    <!-- dynamic feature module-->
    <include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_login"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.login"
        app:graphResName="nav_graph_login"
        app:moduleName="login" />

    <include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_stage"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.stage"
        app:graphResName="nav_graph_stage"
        app:moduleName="stage">

        <argument
            android:name="sessionArgs"
            app:argType="com.smarttoolfactory.domain.model.UserSession" />
    </include-dynamic>

</navigation>
```

In login dynamic feature module navigation is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/nav_graph_login"
    app:moduleName="login"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Login Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_stageFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_stage"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph_login"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <include-dynamic
        android:id="@id/nav_graph_stage"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.stage"
        app:graphResName="nav_graph_stage"
        app:moduleName="stage">

        <argument
            android:name="sessionArgs"
            app:argType="com.smarttoolfactory.domain.model.UserSession" />
    </include-dynamic>
</navigation>
```

in a fragment in app module it's possible to navigate via

```
        val direction = MainFragmentDirections
            .actionMainFragmentToLoginFragment()

        findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

With JetPackCompose navigation is applied for a single module app with

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "profile") {
    composable("profile") { Profile(/*...*/) }
    composable("friendslist") { FriendsList(/*...*/) }
    /*...*/
}
```

in the code above you have each composable in app module for a single module app. Since app cannot know about feature modules is there a way to navigate from app to dynamic feature modules or between dynamic feature modules without using any Fragments as destinations?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing. Unfortunately its not available yet.
There is currently a feature request for this.

issue link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183677219